# Ayuda con function PHP de descarte de un dato MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql, php7

poseo lo siguiente:

```
$verf = "SELECT nro_transf FROM pedidos WHERE nro_transf = '$nro_transf'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $verf);
$rows =  mysqli_num_rows($result);

$verf2 = "SELECT nro_transf FROM pagos WHERE nro_transf = '$nro_transf'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $verf2);
$rows2 =  mysqli_num_rows($result2);

$sumarows = $rows + $rows2;
```

Prácticamente lo que ocupo es que si el dato suministrado por el usuario en mi formulario de declaración de pagos ya existe en mi base de datos entonces no acepte la declaración (Estos if ya los tengo declarados y funcionales) tal cual como lo tengo funciona si y solo si el numero que se intenta utilizar es exactamente igual al numero que existe en mi base de datos, pero me he encontrado con que hay usuarios que si ejemplo ya existe la declaracion:
nro_transf = 123456
Ellos tratan de engañar colocando un numero similar ejemplo:
nro_transf = 1123456
nro_transf = 00123456
nro_transf = 01123456
**Mi consulta seria:**
Que instruccion le puedo dar a mis 2 querys para que aparte de buscar el numero tal cual fue ingresado tambien lo haga si los ultimos 6 digitos son similares..! 
Se que con la instruccion:

```
WHERE (nro_transf LIKE '%$nro_transf%')
```

puedo hacer el filtro pero resulta que hay transferencias que casi el 100% de las mismas empiezan con los mismos digitos ejemplo:
0051411234
0051413456
0051416789
Donde todas son transferencias validas pero empiezan con el mismo numero y lo ideal es filtrar por sus ultimos 4 o 6 digitos que si son diferentes.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, si eso lo intente pero como lo indique en mi enunciado si en mi BD existe un `nro_transf = 0987654321` y alguien intenta declarar el numero 09987654321 este dato no es filtrado ya que lo considera otro numero.

Comment: SI claro, es otro numero, los numeros de las transferencias bancarias normalmente son como la indique ejemplo **0987654321** pero hay muchos usuarios que intentan declarar sus pagos con el mismo numero colocandole un numero intercalado y normalmente lo hacen entre el digito 0 y el digito 2 ya que por lo menos en Venezuela se puede conformar una transferencia con los ultimos 6 digitos del numero de operacion bancaria que se suministra, entonces lo que deseo hacer es que si los ultimos digitos coinciden con alguno existente en mi base de datos entonces sea filtrado por alguno de mis query.

Comment: Si no hay alguna funcion via SQL para hacerlo estaba pensando en extraer de la variable `$nro_transf` los ultimos 4 digitos y colocarlo como un like dentro de mi query..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corta la cadena antes de pasarsela al query.

Para ello, usa la funcion [substr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php), la cual te va a permitir quedarte con una porción de ella.

Por ejemplo, crea una nueva variable:

```
$numerocorto = substr($nro_transf, -6);
```

Y esa nueva variable va a tener los ultimos 6 caracteres de nro_transf.

Y despues, en tu query, hacelo normalmente usando la condición:

```
WHERE (nro_transf LIKE '%$numerocorto')
```

sin el % al final, ya que lo que va a hacer ahi es traerte todo lo igual a los ultimos 6 digitos que extrajiste previamente

Comment: Simplemente perfecto.. Gracias..!!

Answer (score -1):

Intenta quitando los dos **%** para que tu busqueda sea exactamente con el dato que lleva tu variable **$nro_transf** de esa manera tu busqueda sera exacta.

Comment: Gracias por intentar ayudar, muy valioso de tu parte, pero creo que no comprendiste mi planteamiento, de hecho alli explico que yo estoy utilizando en mi query la sentencia `WHERE nro_transf = '$nro_transf'` que hace la búsqueda exacta del numero suministrado, yo ocupo es en hacer que si los ultimos 6 digitos son iguales entonces se filtre como true el `mysqli_num_rows` o en su defecto la manera correcta de hacer mi planteamiento del query.